# cannot implicity convert type 'int' to 'int[]'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I define an array in my code for example :

```
int[] number ={0,2,3}

int[] result = (from p in number where n==3 select n).First();
```

I get error :

> cannot implicity convert type 'int' to 'int[]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problematic line:

```
int[] result = (from p in number where n==3 select n).First();
```

With `First()` you get a single `int` and assign it to `result`, which is an `int[]`. The left-hand-side expects an array and gets an `int` instead. Possible fix:

```
int result = (from p in number where n==3 select n).First();
```

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

`.First()` takes a collection and returns the first object, hence the result is of `int` type.